# Is there a term for "blue balls" in Japanese?

Tags: words

Blue balls: testicular pain caused by prolonged sexual arousal in the human male without ejaculation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_balls

Is there a term for it in Japanese? If so, what is it? If not, what would be the closest way to express it?

Comment: Vascular congestion in general is called 鬱血（うっけつ）, but it's not what you want, is it?

Comment: Not really, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any specific term for it in japanese.

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=blue+balls
http://abcdane.net/archives/200503/akushuimi.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a exact translation but you could try to express the resulting mood using むらむら (horny) or もやもや (hazy, murky, in a sense of not being fulfilled).